# how to fix "openerp.osv.expression: Field 'Sale Order' (sale_id) can not be searched: non-stored function field without fnct_search"

Tags: linux, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

When I write the code of getting the tracking status

> openerp.osv.expression: Field 'Sale Order' (sale_id) can not be
>   searched: non-stored function field without fnct_search

this error is caused.how to fix it?

From wizard when check mark is checked then call the method for tracking status.

Comment: Where is the code this error happens? Please add your custom code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot search for fields that are not stored in the database. By default, the function fields do not get stored in the database.

You have two options here, you either use `store=True` to the definition of your field so that the field is indeed stored in the database and you can search on it **or** you can provide a [fnct_search](https://members.hellug.gr/xrg/openerp-doc/html/api_reference/osv/fields_function.html) method that will perform the searching and return the result.